# How to retrieve the id of a object in weaviate java Client

Tags: java, weaviate, vector-database

i want to update an existing object in weaviate db. I find the object using neartext or using where filter, But i need object id to update, Any suggestion to do that, In python using  **_additional(id)**, id property can be retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package io.weaviate;

import io.weaviate.client.Config;
import io.weaviate.client.WeaviateClient;
import io.weaviate.client.base.Result;
import io.weaviate.client.v1.graphql.model.GraphQLResponse;
import io.weaviate.client.v1.graphql.query.argument.NearTextArgument;
import io.weaviate.client.v1.graphql.query.fields.Field;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Config config = new Config("http", "localhost:8080");
  WeaviateClient client = new WeaviateClient(config);

  Field title = Field.builder().name("title").build();
  Field _additional = Field.builder().name("_additional").fields(new Field[]{
    Field.builder().name("id").build(),
    Field.builder().name("distance").build()
  }).build();

NearTextArgument explore = client.graphQL().arguments().nearTextArgBuilder()
  .concepts(new String[]{ "fashion" })
  .build();

Result<GraphQLResponse> result = client.graphQL().get()
  .withClassName("Article")
  .withFields(title, _additional)
  .withNearText(explore)
  .run();
if (result.hasErrors()) {
  System.out.println(result.getError());
  return;
}
System.out.println(result.getResult());  }   }
```

found the solution from their documentation